# Get screen height in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

My goal is to get screen height in Jade with this:

```
- var screenHeight = screen.height;
```

but it doesn't work. Later I use this variable in dynamically formed URL's of images in "src" attribute for different screen sizes.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `screen.height` should work. what do you get in `var screenHeight` ?

Comment: `jade` is template engine of html !!! and you are talking about `height` . how it could be possible ??

Comment: Sorry, my fault... it works perfectly,  as expected. But in compile time (I use webpack) there were some errors "get height property of undefined" (or something like this). Thank you!

Comment: KishanOza read about "Using JavaScript in Jade", there is special syntax for this and this feature is absolutely legal.